# SA_RESTART not defined under Linux, compiles fine in Solaris

Tags: linux, solaris, signals, c99

**Disclaimer:** This is for a programming class, but it is **not** the answer or purpose of the assignment.

We have access to multiple *nix-like servers in my university, and are encouraged to compile our projects on each of them to see how different environments change things. I'm currently doing a project that involves signals and I've hit a difference that I cannot fix myself.

Under a Solaris based server, everything works:

```
xxxxxxx@xxx:~/proj6$ make gcc-new
rm -f ./pr6
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -o pr6 pr6.2.c pr6_ctime.c pr6_signal.c
 pr6_signal.c:64: warning: unused parameter 'sig'
 pr6_signal.c:64: warning: unused parameter 'func'
```

Under a Linux based server, I see this:

```
xxxxxxx@xxxxx:~/proj6$ make gcc-new
rm -f ./pr6
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS  -o pr6  pr6.2.c pr6_ctime.c pr6_signal.c
pr6_signal.c: In function âinstall_signal_handlerâ:
pr6_signal.c:45: error: âSA_RESTARTâ undeclared (first use in this function)
pr6_signal.c:45: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
pr6_signal.c:45: error: for each function it appears in.)
pr6_signal.c: In function âreinstall_signal_handlerâ:
pr6_signal.c:64: warning: unused parameter âsigâ
pr6_signal.c:64: warning: unused parameter âfuncâ
make: *** [gcc-new] Error 1
```

I've fiddled around with different combinations of c99, POSIX 2001-12, and POSIX pthread to no avail. I don't understand why it is that `SA_RESTART` would not be defined under Linux as it is part of the POSIX standard and I've included that flag on GCC. If I forgot to #include something then it should be absent on both systems, no?

UPDATE:

I used `gcc -M` to determine which files are included in my compile on each machine and then used `grep` to try to find the definition. So far these are my results:

(On Solaris)

```
xxxxxxx@xxx:~/proj6$ grep "SA_RESTART" /usr/include/sys/signal.h
#define SA_RESTART      0x000004
xxxxxxx@xxx:~/proj6$ grep "SA_RESTART" ./linux-signal.h
xxxxxxx@xxx:~/proj6$



xxxxxxx@xxx:~/proj6$ grep "#include" ./linux-signal.h
#include <features.h>
#include <bits/sigset.h>                /* __sigset_t, __sig_atomic_t.  */
#include <bits/types.h>
#include <bits/signum.h>
xxxxxxx@xxx:~/proj6$ grep "#include" /usr/include/sys/signal.h
#include <sys/feature_tests.h>
#include <sys/iso/signal_iso.h>
#include <sys/siginfo.h>
#include <sys/ucontext.h>
#include <sys/t_lock.h>
```

(On Linux)

```
xxxxxxx@xxxxx:~/proj6$ grep "SA_RESTART" /usr/include/features.h
xxxxxxx@xxxxx:~/proj6$ grep "SA_RESTART" /usr/include/bits/sigset.h 
xxxxxxx@xxxxx:~/proj6$ grep "SA_RESTART" /usr/include/bits/types.h
xxxxxxx@xxxxx:~/proj6$ grep "SA_RESTART" /usr/include/bits/signum.h
xxxxxxx@xxxxx:~/proj6$
```

So there is no definition for SA_RESTART in any of the files being included under Linux (the compiler told me this to start with) so the question is WHY?

Update #2: contents of `/usr/include/sys/signal.h` on Linux is just `#include

Update #3: output of `grep -r SA_RESTART /usr/include`

```
/usr/include/bits/sigaction.h:# define SA_RESTART   0x10000000 /* Restart syscall on signal return.  */
/usr/include/asm-generic/signal.h: * SA_RESTART flag to get restarting signals (which were the default long ago)
/usr/include/asm-generic/signal.h:#define SA_RESTART    0x10000000
Binary file /usr/include/c++/3.4.6/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/stdc++.h.gch/O2g matches
Binary file /usr/include/c++/3.4.6/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/stdc++.h.gch/O0g matches
/usr/include/mysql/my_pthread.h:  as Mac OS X, sigset() results in flags such as SA_RESTART being set, and
/usr/include/asm/signal.h: * SA_RESTART flag to get restarting signals (which were the default long ago)
/usr/include/asm/signal.h:#define SA_RESTART    0x10000000u
grep: warning: /usr/include/gphoto2/gphoto2: recursive directory loop

/usr/include/valgrind/vki/vki-ppc64-linux.h:#define VKI_SA_RESTART      0x10000000u
/usr/include/valgrind/vki/vki-darwin.h:#define VKI_SA_RESTART   SA_RESTART
/usr/include/valgrind/vki/vki-ppc32-linux.h:#define VKI_SA_RESTART              0x10000000
/usr/include/valgrind/vki/vki-x86-linux.h:#define VKI_SA_RESTART                0x10000000u
/usr/include/valgrind/vki/vki-s390x-linux.h: * SA_RESTART flag to get restarting signals (which were the default long ago)
/usr/include/valgrind/vki/vki-s390x-linux.h:#define VKI_SA_RESTART      0x10000000
/usr/include/valgrind/vki/vki-amd64-linux.h:#define VKI_SA_RESTART              0x10000000
/usr/include/valgrind/vki/vki-arm-linux.h:#define VKI_SA_RESTART                0x10000000u
```

So it resides in a file called sigaction.h (which makes sense) and that file is being included (verified with `gcc -M`), so why is the compiler complaining?

Comment: "If I forgot to #include something then it should be absent on both systems, no?"  I don't understand that argument at all.  You can trivially imagine a system where `#include <unistd.h>` happens to `#include <signal.h>`, and `SA_RESTART` would be present even without the required header, and another where it doesn't.  I don't what things look like on Solaris.

Comment: @ephemient I was considering that so I did more searching. See updated post

Comment: SA_RESTART is declared directly in `sys/signal.h` on Solaris, and I couldn't find it in Linux's `signal.h` or any of the files that it includes.

Comment: What about `grep -r SA_RESTART /usr/include`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's due to your -D flag:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
#ifdef SA_RESTART
    puts("have SA_RESTART");
#else
    puts("no SA_RESTART");
#endif
    return 0;
}

$ cc foo.c && ./a.out
have SA_RESTART
$ gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS foo.c && ./a.out
no SA_RESTART
$ gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS foo.c && ./a.out
have SA_RESTART
```

In particular, "200112L" means "don't give me SA_RESTART".  See `/usr/include/features.h`.

Edit: as [Andrew Henle notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828733/sa-restart-not-defined-under-linux-compiles-fine-in-solaris/9829389?noredirect=1#comment118875829_9829389), this particular Linux `features.h` is (or was back in 2012) just plain wrong here: see the [SUS spec from 1997](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/signal.h.html).  Still, if it's wrong in whatever system you're using, you may need to work around that.

Comment: Thanks, it is odd that our professor would have told use to use 200112L specifically but failed to mention this. I guess I'll have to bring this up with him. Thanks.

Comment: 200112L obviously works fine on Solaris.  There are multiple revs of the POSIX standard and I thought `SA_RESTART` was older than 2008, but apparently not, at least if the Linux features.h has it right. :-)

Comment: @torek Way late, here, but, ummm, no. Linux is *wrong* here. [`SA_RESTART` was defined in SUSv2 by 1997](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/signal.h.html) and might even predate even that.  The [Solaris `signal.h` header properly uses an XPG4.2-based test](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/9ecd05bdc59e4a1091c51ce68cce2028d5ba6fd1/usr/src/uts/common/sys/signal.h#L130).

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Interesting. So Linux should get patched, if it hasn't already been. Still, one must often work with what one has (work around the bug). In any case I'll add your link and the note that it appears that Linux had this wrong.

Comment: @torek I have no idea what's going on with Linux, especially glibc.  Maybe [glibc's `sigaction.h`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/sigaction.h) `SA_RESTART` requires the 2008 POSIX C source defined because [`SA_RESTART` is listed as an extension in POSIX 2001](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html#tag_13_43).  But then `SA_SIGINFO` is also listed as an extension by the same standard yet `sigaction.h` defines that unconditionally.

Comment: But the Linux `signal.h` headers appear to define `SA_RESTART` unconditionally now.  I'm not sure why glibc's `sigaction.h` is a straggler, nor why it ignores the 1997 SUSv2 standard.  Consistency would be nice...